# Material UI - Show adornments vertically in TextField

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to show adornments vertically in material ui Textfield but no luck. It's always positioned horizontally. Is there a way to show adornments vertically?

**Code:**

```
<TextField 
   variant="filled" 
   fullWidth 
   multiline 
   rowsMax={7}
   onFocus={() => handleInputFocus({})}
   onBlur={() => handleInputFocus({})}
   InputProps={{
   ...(isSelected ? { endAdornment:
   <InputAdornment position="start">
      <Box mb={3}>
         <SaveIcon color="primary" className={cursorStyle} onClick={() => deleteNote()} />
         <DeleteIcon className={cursorStyle} onClick={() => deleteNote()} />
      </Box>
    </InputAdornment> }: {})
  }}
/>
```

**Actual Output:** [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use display flex, try to add `style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column'}}` in InputAdornment line as `<InputAdornment position="start" style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column'}}>`

Then just fix your icon's style. Because probably they will be out of the box boundaries.

Comment: Cool it worked but I had to remove Box which is inside InputAdornment. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad that it helped. Actually if Box is necessary for your component you can try to add style into Box instead of InputAdornment. But im not sure if it works as you wish.